# Que recurso encontro em HTML, como opção ao Include do PHP?

Tags: div

Que recursos encontro dentro de uma página HTML, para tornar segmentos independentes de uma página, (Head, Body, footer e etc.) assim como acontece usando o include?
Para que uma página só fosse suficiente, diante de 30 páginas que usaria a mesma informação.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação da W3C exitem duas maneiras para vc fazer isso.

> Sometimes, rather than linking to a document, an author may want to
>   embed it directly into a primary HTML document. Authors may use either
>   the IFRAME element or the OBJECT element for this purpose

Documentação sobre o `<object>`: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html

Forma de usar:

```
<OBJECT data="embed_me.html">
Warning: embed_me.html could not be embedded.
</OBJECT>
```

---

Documentação sobre o `<iframe>`: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#edef-IFRAME

Forma de usar:

```
<IFRAME src="foo.html" width="400" height="500" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
  [Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured
  not to display frames. However, you may visit
  <A href="foo.html">the related document.</A>]
</IFRAME>
```

**OBS1:** Para os dois métodos acima existe um série de particularidades! *Não deixe de ler a documentação...*

**OBS2:** Independente disso eu indico usar o `include` mesmo e em último caso, `required_once` também com `PHP`

Comment: Obrigado Hugo. Estou dando uma olhada na documentação.